# Decrementing Array Round Robin Style

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, array-algorithms

I have an array that can have a really large size holding values I need to decrement to 0. And I have a total amount I can decrement this array by. The problem is I want to decrement it round robin style, and return the indices that holds a value equals to 0.

Is there any faster way besides going into a for/while loop and decrementing it one by one? I do think there's a smarter way to do it, but I'm just not sure what that would be.

```
t = 30 #amount I can decrement by

A = [2,4,5,20,10,40,3,8,11,1] #could be as large as a million values inside

#Array after decrement: [0, 0, 1, 16, 7, 37, 0, 5, 8, 0]

Returns indices: [0,1,6,9]
```

Comment: Sort it.  Do your arithmetic on the smallest values.  Unsort it (you did remember to keep the sort permutation from the first step didn't you!). Figure out, if you want to, at what point two sorts and a little arithmetic will be faster than multiple scans through the entire array.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark What kind of arithmetic do I need to do? I was thinking about dividing t by the length of the A and subtracting each element by that amount and figuring out the leftover values, and applying it on the unsorted array again. But that has a lot edge cases to handle, so I think I'm heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Work through the example in your question with pencil and paper, you'll figure it out very quickly.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Really sorry for bothering. I tried to do it pen and paper, but I just can't seem to figure a simple way out. Do you have any hints you can give me?

Comment: Question about the actual "code" in your post: if you're removing 30, spread over your stated array, which is 10 elements long, you remove 3 from each index. So how does `[2,4,5,...` turn into `[0,0,1,...`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Once a value is decremented to 0, I don't want to decrement it anymore, so it'll move to the next value.

Comment: That's a pretty important detail: please [add that to your post](/help/how-to-ask). And having said that: please also show the code you already have.